# expdp does not always export all tables in a schema

Tags: oracle, expdp

I am attempting to dump a database using expdp.  I am using the oracle 11g client on Solaris, and calling it with a parameter file containing the following : SCHEMAS=my_schema DUMPFILE=DUMPFILE.dmp LOGFILE=logfile.log PARALLEL=1 VERSION=COMPATIBLE COMPRESSION=NONE.  I am exporting a single schema from a multischema database.

Usually this works properly, however there are times when not all of the tables in the schema are exported, even though expdp reports a successful export.  In this situation, a report of an attempt to export the missing tables does not appear anywhere in the logfile.

What could cause expdp to fail to export some of the tables on one execution, while the dump from the next execution (using the same script/parameterfiles/database/schema) does contain all of the tables?

Comment: Probably not it, but worth a mention: permissions? Does the account performing the expdp have permissions on the missing tables?

Comment: Something must be different, though you seem sure it isn't. Are the row counts on the tables that do work consistent, and correct? The only thing I can immediately think of is that you have a TNS alias that load balances to different instances, and at some point they've become separate DBs. That seems rather unlikely though. Is it always the same tables that are missing, and is there anything different about those - are they new, or IOTs, or... anything like that?

Comment: Answer to question is on server fault https://serverfault.com/questions/143794/oracle-11gr2-exp-does-not-export-some-tables